# Explanation required regarding Double destruction of exception objects

Tags: c++, exception

In his insightful paper,
**[Error and Exception Handling](http://www.boost.org/community/error_handling.html),**
***[@Dave Abrahams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125349/dave-abrahams)*** says:

> **Make your exception class immune to double-destruction if possible**. Unfortunately, several popular compilers occasionally cause exception objects to be destroyed twice. If you can arrange for that to be harmless (e.g. by zeroing deleted pointers) your code will be more robust.

I am not able to understand this particular guideline, Can someone:

1. Please provide a code example of this double destruction scenario &
2. What is the best way to implement a custom exception class to avoid this?

Comment: According to [this thread](http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.c++.moderated/exception-objects-to-be-destroyed-twi/104604), it's a bug in the compiler that causes double destruction.

Comment: @chrisaycock: oh, I didn't do a google search on this one before posting,I thought perhaps my doubt was too specific or trivial that anyone would have the same doubt.Which brings me another Q ***Is this guideline still relevant?***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like @Tony said, this guideline was meant as a protection against compiler bugs. This guideline dates back to 2001 or so, when exceptions support was probably still a bit unstable. Since then, I think/hope most compilers have fixed this bug, so the guideline might not be very relevant anymore.

FWIW, this guideline has been eliminated from [the CERT coding practices](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/VOID+Make+exception+objects+immune+to+double+destruction). In the discussion on this page, an interesting point is raised: destructing an object twice is UB anyway, so whatever you do to handle that in your classes will never make your program fully predictible.

However, if you really want your code to be portable across compilers (including old versions), you should probably take all these little glitches into account. For instance, Boost goes through a lot of work to work around compiler bugs; they could simply write standard-compliant code and defer the responsability of failures to implementations, but that would hinder the adoption of their libraries.

Whether you need to put the same care when writing your code depends on your requirements, and basically boils down to this question: is supporting dozens of compilers really worth the amount of work that implies?

Answer (score 3):

To quote from Article by @chrisaycock:

> "why destroy twice"? Because of compiler bugs, that's why! This is an
>   error, compilers should not do this. But they do. I worked on a
>   project where I got bitten by this using Sun's Studio8 compiler. I
>   created a ostringstream object in a catch clause and found it got
>   destructed twice. To fix it I moved it to before the try, then it
>   worked. This sort of bug does not happen very often. Most of the time
>   creating objects in the catch clause was ok but it is something to be
>   aware of.
>
> Regards,
>
> Andrew Marlow

Comment: Raises me a number of questions: ***"Is this guideline still relevant?"***, ***"Should the code I write also take in to account compiler bugs?"***. Writing Standard adhering UB free code is difficult enough should I also take care of all these things?

Comment: +1 Tony thanks for the answer, @LucTouraille, Nicely expressed.If you can please combine both your comments and post it as an answer I will be happy to mark it as accepted answer.The comment about guideline has been eliminated answers one my of questions in specific.

Answer (score 1):

There is no scenario in the Standard where one object may be destructed twice. Any instance where this occurs is a bug on behalf of the user, or, where the object is destructed by the compiler such as an exception, then the compiler bug. I have never heard of such a bug prior to now in any major compiler, and see no reason to believe that it will be problematic for anyone writing C++ code in general.

Comment: Indeed, destroying the same object twice is an guaranteed Undefined Behavior and I have never encountered any such scenario, hence the question.+1 Thanks for the answer though.